# Difference between Grid and GridSplitter

Tags: c#, wpf

I am new to wpf.I know well to use Grid control.But i don't know where should i use GridSplitter,the use of GridSplitter and why should i use it.Please tell me the difference.

Comment: I'm sorry, but did you read the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.gridsplitter.aspx) documentation? It has a good description of what it does and how to use it.

Comment: check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff382751(v=vs.95).aspx) and [this](http://www.ehow.com/how_4546867_use-gridsplitter-wpf.html)

Answer (score 2):

A grid is used for layout. For example, you can say your grid has 2 columns and 2 rows with `Width="*"`, then they will size automatically to take up a quarter of the space.
Now if you want to resize them (like with the navigation pane on the left of windows explorer, you can drag the border to change its width), you can use a GridSplitter. That enables you to grab the edge between the grid's columns (or rows) and resize them.

The grey line that you can drag is a GridSplitter: 
[image: GridSplitter Example]